# How should the file upload process be on Laravel according to SOLID principles?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's do a file upload on Laravel. But where should we do this according to SOLID principles? Controller? Or Repostory? where is?

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request){


        $files = $request->file('attachment');
    
        if($request->hasFile('attachment'))
        {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file->store('users/' . $this->user->id . '/messages');
            }

            return redirect()->route('fileupload.form')
            ->with('status', true)
            ->with('msg', __('File upload successful'));
        }
    }

}
```

OR?

Comment: If you mean database repository then that is only for abstracting that layer, it wouldn't handle dealing with the request directly or the upload process

Comment: I'm new to Laravel. Where should I do the file upload process?

Comment: Laravel uses the MVC pattern. According to this pattern: Views sends the data to controller (meaning the file upload already happend here), controllers fills the data using the models and you execute some sort of save function. In your case your controller should tell your model where the file (that was uploaded) is located. After calling the save function of the model, you should react properly: model should do all sorts of checks and move the file into the correct location.

Comment: Can I see an example on this subject? @DefinitelynotRafal

Comment: There might be an specific example on this subject somewhere. But [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is an idea and is there for abstract. There is no difference in sending files and/or strings in this case. If you want to follow this pattern: controller tells the model the location of the uploaded file and the model needs to do the rest (once save is called).

Comment: I guess the 'php artisan make: model FileUpload' you mentioned as a model is not the model created with this command? I'm sorry I'm trying to understand the concepts and I want to follow SOLID principles. @DefinitelynotRafal

Comment: You need to understand first of all that file upload happens automatically once you have a form with `<input type="file"/>` somewhere. Your webserver does this automatically and stores the file in a temporary folder. So the upload already happend. The controller just tells the model where the file is which should be used. The models are responsible for getting/updating/deleting data (= S in SOLID), how they do it, is their secret, if they store it in a database or save the file in a folder, doesnt matter, its their secret.

Comment: Yes, even if it is an empty php file, the uploaded file is transferred to the server due to the settings specified on php.ini. What I want to understand here is just the structure. For example, when we register a member. We first submit the information in our FormRequest class to validate and pass it through the rules here.  Then we perform database registration in UserRepostroy interface. Finally, we direct it in our Usercontroller file.  return redirect()->route('success.user') @DefinitelynotRafal

Answer (score 2):

I rather to create a service for uploading files. Something like below:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\UploadException;

class Upload
{

    /**
     * Store media and return path
     *
     * @param UploadedFile|UploadedFile[]|null $uploadedFile
     * @param $store_path
     * @param bool $get_path_only
     * @return array|string|null
     */
    public function store($uploadedFile, $store_path, $get_path_only = true)
    {
        if ($uploadedFile->isValid()) {
            $path          = $uploadedFile->store($store_path, 'public');
            $original_name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

            if ($get_path_only) return $path;

            return [$path, $original_name];

        } else {
            throw new UploadException("Uploaded file is not valid.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need a binding for that, it will resolve without one

Comment: Yes, just call it via the namespace to use why you're connecting it. No need as there is no dependency injection.

Comment: @Pasalar this is the idea of pushing this functionality off to something else to worry about and that thing has a single responsibility ... the term 'service' is a lil nebulous but this is the idea of that

Comment: @lagbox I use binding for this for two reasons. 1. I dont need anymore to make a new instance of this class like (new Upload) if I use singleton. 2. I have some other methods in this class which need dependency injection. So, why I should not use binding?

Comment: the container resolves classes automatically, via reflection "There is no need to bind classes into the container if they do not depend on any interfaces. The container does not need to be instructed on how to build these objects, since it can automatically resolve these objects using reflection." ... bindings are only needed if the container can NOT resolve something automatically or you have specific configuration you need for a particular instance

Comment: Thank you @lagbox. I will update my answer.